# Azure DevOps for multiple small projects

Tags: agile, scrum, azure-devops

We are a software development company with less than 10 employees. Each employee may be a part of multiple projects. Also, the project manager may look after multiple projects as well. We use Azure DevOps to keep track of work items in each project.

The problems we face are

1. Because we don't work on only one project, it becomes difficult to see what is scheduled on a single page. We have to go in iteration/sprint for each project.
2. The projects we work on do not ship deployments continuously, hence the iteration of 1 week sometimes become too big for one project since we may not have enough changes for that project.

We really like using Azure DevOps for development, but once the support/maintenance phase starts, it becomes confusing due to the above points. Any suggestions on what we can do differently?

Comment: how have you got it setup? I had a look and it seemed to me that one project with multiple teams and all the repos was the way to go

Comment: @Ewan, in that case, can we restrict the stakeholders to see only workitems related to their projects?

Comment: assign to the teams they are in

Answer (score 3):

1) I'd suggest [Delivery Plans](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.vss-plans), that helps you have a look at multiple projects/organizations, but works well if you set iterations.

It's free for Azure DevOps.

2) You could set different capacity based on the planned deliveries, and allocate more resources on certain projects when you need it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Delivery Plans will help us for sure. We are evaluating the use of capacity.